# Cant set up a Neo4j core cluster

Tags: ongdb

I cant setup a cluster on product machine ; there is no error in log, but the cluster cant do leader election;

Neo4j.conf:

```
dbms.mode=CORE
causal_clustering.minimum_core_cluster_size_at_formation=3
causal_clustering.minimum_core_cluster_size_at_runtime=3
causal_clustering.initial_discovery_members=localhost:5000,localhost:5001,localhost:5002
causal_clustering.discovery_listen_address=:5000
causal_clustering.transaction_listen_address=:6000
causal_clustering.raft_listen_address=:7000
```

netstat -tunlp

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8742/java           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7002          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8866/java           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8619/java           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8742/java           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5002          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8866/java           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8619/java
```

Debug_log: the log stoped on this step, and no more

```
2022-08-18 02:32:11.613+0000 INFO [o.n.c.d.SecureHazelcastCoreTopologyService] Discovering other core members in initial members set: [localhost:5002, localhost:5001, localhost:5000]
2022-08-18 02:32:11.658+0000 INFO [o.n.c.c.c.l.s.SegmentedRaftLog] log started with recovered state State{prevIndex=-1, prevTerm=-1, appendIndex=-1}
2022-08-18 02:32:11.659+0000 INFO [o.n.c.c.c.m.RaftMembershipManager] Membership state before recovery: RaftMembershipState{committed=null, appended=null, ordinal=-1}
2022-08-18 02:32:11.659+0000 INFO [o.n.c.c.c.m.RaftMembershipManager] Recovering from: -1 to: -1
2022-08-18 02:32:11.660+0000 INFO [o.n.c.c.c.m.RaftMembershipManager] Membership state after recovery: RaftMembershipState{committed=null, appended=null, ordinal=-1}
2022-08-18 02:32:11.660+0000 INFO [o.n.c.c.c.m.RaftMembershipManager] Target membership: []
2022-08-18 02:32:12.039+0000 INFO [o.n.c.n.Server] raft-server: bound to 127.0.0.1:7000
2022-08-18 02:32:21.235+0000 INFO [o.n.c.d.SecureHazelcastCoreTopologyService] Cluster discovery service started
2022-08-18 02:32:21.406+0000 INFO [o.n.c.d.CoreMonitor] Bound to cluster with id 095f1809-5bd9-47c4-85e7-4aac2db1f866
2022-08-18 02:32:21.413+0000 INFO [o.n.c.d.SecureHazelcastCoreTopologyService] Core topology changed {added=[{memberId=MemberId{84056e50}, info=CoreServerInfo{raftServer=localhost:7001, catchupServer=localhost:6001, clientConnectorAddresses=bolt://localhost:7688,http://localhost:7475,https://localhost:6475, groups=[], database=default, refuseToBeLeader=false}}], removed=[]}
2022-08-18 02:32:21.413+0000 INFO [o.n.c.c.c.m.RaftMembershipManager] Target membership: [MemberId{84056e50}]
2022-08-18 02:32:21.465+0000 INFO [o.n.c.d.CoreMonitor] Discovered core member at localhost:5001
2022-08-18 02:32:28.388+0000 INFO [o.n.c.d.CoreMonitor] Discovered core member at localhost:5002
2022-08-18 02:32:28.393+0000 INFO [o.n.c.d.SecureHazelcastCoreTopologyService] Core topology changed {added=[{memberId=MemberId{960e78d6}, info=CoreServerInfo{raftServer=localhost:7002, catchupServer=localhost:6002, clientConnectorAddresses=bolt://localhost:7689,http://localhost:7476,https://localhost:6476, groups=[], database=default, refuseToBeLeader=false}}], removed=[]}
2022-08-18 02:32:28.393+0000 INFO [o.n.c.c.c.m.RaftMembershipManager] Target membership: [MemberId{960e78d6}, MemberId{84056e50}]
2022-08-18 02:34:05.925+0000 INFO [o.n.c.p.h.HandshakeServerInitializer] Installing handshake server local /127.0.0.1:7000 remote /127.0.0.1:57072
```

Comment: neo4j version ongdb-enterprise-3.6.0

Comment: that's not Neo4j, that's ongdb.